# combine, etoc and memoir

Tags: memoir, combine, etoc

I'm trying to get the `combine` class to work together with `etoc`. Particularly I have an article/chapter which has its own local toc. See the following chapter1.tex:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocdepth{paragraph}
\begin{document}

\etocsettocdepth.toc{paragraph}
\chapter{A chapter}
\etocsettocstyle{\section*{\contentsname}}{}
\localtableofcontents*
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\end{document}
```

By itself this file compiles fine, except of

> Package etoc Warning: You may consider using \etocsettocdepth.toc as a
>   drop-in  replacement to the memoir own \settocdepth if you wish to
>   exploit etoc to its  fullest. Similarly consider using
>   \etocsettocdepth and \etocsetnexttocdepth  rather than memoir's
>   \maxtocdepth. on input line 4.

If then I try to get this loaded into the following main file of `combine` class both the main and the local tocs break:

```
\documentclass[memoir]{combine}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{papers}

\coltoctitle{Article number 1}
\coltocauthor{Author number 1}
\label{art1}
\import{chapter1}

\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `combine` have you considered `docmute`, it will just ignore the preamble of included (`\input` or `\include`), I tend to use that instead of `combine`. Though I've never used `etoc`

Comment: @daleif, no I had not looked into it so far. A first attempt now looks promising, I've solved above problem with ease. Let me see how it works with my real files. I'm not sure though if I can harmonise my different documents' preambles, which would be required.

Comment: I use it for conference abstracts. The participants get a general template and the instruction that they are not allowed to add anything to the preamble. It works fine.

Comment: The warning issued by `etoc` under class memoir will be a simple informative message, which will cause less alarm, starting with version `1.08g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independently of `etoc` there seems to be currently (up-to-date TL2015) an incompatibility of `combine` vs `memoir`.

Bottom of answer addresses `etoc+book+combine` compatibility ; I have made no attempt for `etoc+memoir+combine` because I observe already problems with `memoir+combine`, which I describe first.

### Test of book with combine: ok

No problems with the following files using combine and the `book` class:

File `testcombine-book.tex`

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{papers}

\coltoctitle{Article number 1}
\coltocauthor{Author number 1}

\label{art1}
\import{testcombine-book-chap1}

\coltoctitle{Article number 2}
\coltocauthor{Author number 2}

\label{art2}
\import{testcombine-book-chap2}

\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

File `testcombine-book-chap1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter (FIRST PAPER)}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\end{document}
```

File `testcombine-book-chap2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter (SECOND PAPER)}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\end{document}
```

Compilation proceeds with no errors and gives expected result.

### Test of memoir with combine: problem

On the other hand the very similar files using `memoir` class create a problem:

```
% file testcombine-memoir.tex
\documentclass[memoir]{combine}
% there is a problem with memoir+combine independently of etoc
% tested 2015-08-30, up-to-date TeXLive 2015

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{papers}

\coltoctitle{Article number 1}
\coltocauthor{Author number 1}

\label{art1}
\import{testcombine-memoir-chap1}

\coltoctitle{Article number 2}
\coltocauthor{Author number 2}

\label{art2}
\import{testcombine-memoir-chap2}

\end{papers}
\end{document}

% file testcombine-memoir-chap1.tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A chapter (FIRST PAPER)}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\end{document}

% file testcombine-memoir-chap2.tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A chapter (SECOND PAPER)}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\end{document}
```

Compilation of these files end up in this error:

```
% gives 
% ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \sf@@memsub@label already defined.

% --- TeX said ---
%                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

% See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
% Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
%  ...                                              

% l.9 \begin{document}
% referring to testcombine-memoir-chap1
```

and a similar one when importing the second paper.

### etoc vs combine compatibility problems

This being said, `etoc` is currently incompatible with the `combine` class: I can add use of `etoc` to the `book` class files above:

```
\usepackage{etoc}
% inside main file, also add this :
% make coltoctitle and coltocauthor level known to etoc
\etocsetlevel{coltoctitle}{1}
\etocsetlevel{coltocauthor}{2}
```

and compilation proceeds then with no error, but the mechanism for local tables of contents is broken.

`etoc` records some ids in the `.toc` files for local TOCs. I see this information correctly appearing in the `.aux` files of the imported papers, which get updated on each compilation of the main file. But this information does not make its way to the `.toc` files of the imported papers, those are not re-generated, and the ones which are created on compiling individually each sub-paper contain naturally a wrong id for the local TOCs.

If the sub `.toc` files were regenerated as the `.aux` files are, local table of contents of `etoc` could become functional.

Solving this, if at all possible, needs some effort analyzing the `combine` class code and its interaction with `etoc`: the `.toc` files are correctly regenerated in the absence of `etoc`.

However the code dealing with file opening and closing by `etoc` is not entirely easily patchable, as some piece is not wrapped-up in a macro but added to the add begin document hook literally. Thus solving this issue will presumably also require a new version of `etoc`.

### update: reinstauring compatibility etoc vs combine (book class)

Here are steps to be taken in the main master file to achieve (at least in a simple case) compatibility of `etoc` vs `combine`.

A command `\PatchEtocOpenOut` is defined which must be issued before each use of the `\import` command from the `combine` class.

File `testcombine-etoc-book.tex`:

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}

\usepackage{etoc}
% make coltoctitle and coltocauthor level known to etoc
\etocsetlevel{coltoctitle}{1}
\etocsetlevel{coltocauthor}{2}

% class combine modifies the output streams names
% Inner macro of package etoc must be patched
% (etoc versions 1.08g and earlier)
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\PatchEtocOpenOut {%
% \PatchEtocOpenOut must be issued before
% each use of \import command (after main TOC)
  \Etoc@toctoks {}%
  \def\Etoc@openouttoc
  {%
      \if@filesw
         \immediate \openout \c@ltocfnum \jobname .toc\relax
      \fi
      \global\let\Etoc@openouttoc\empty 
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{papers}

\coltoctitle{Article number 1}
\coltocauthor{Author number 1}
\label{art1}
\PatchEtocOpenOut % must be issued before each \import
\import{testcombine-etoc-book-chap1}

\coltoctitle{Article number 2}
\coltocauthor{Author number 2}
\label{art2}
\PatchEtocOpenOut % must be issued before each \import
\import{testcombine-etoc-book-chap2}

\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

File `testcombine-etoc-book-chap1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocdepth{paragraph}
\etocarticlestyle

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter (FIRST PAPER)}

\localtableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\end{document}
```

File `testcombine-etoc-book-chap2.tex`: (this second chapter has a main toc and two local tocs; all three are produced as expected via compilation of the master file above with the `combine` class.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocdepth{paragraph}

\begin{document}

\etocsettocstyle
  {\section*{\contentsname{} of second paper}}
  {\vspace{.5cm}\hrule}

\tableofcontents

\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{\contentsname{} for this chapter}}{}

\chapter{First chapter (SECOND PAPER)}
\localtableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}

\chapter{Second chapter (SECOND PAPER)}
\localtableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}

\end{document}
```

Compilation of `testcombine-etoc-book.tex` proceeds with  no error and produces expected output with correct import of the two sub-files.